# Merge comments between different posts

Tags: wordpress, merge, comments, posts

I need to replicate the behavior of this site:

http://www.theincipit.com/2013/11/la-notte-di-halloween-tost/9/

As you can see, I linked a "story" divided in various chapters (1-10). Every single chapter, though, displays the same list of comments. So you can comment every chapter but it will go automatically under the same list, displayed in every chapter.

In my site I have different posts grouped in different categories, and I''d like that the same posts form one category display the same list of comments (and when you comment from every post of that category, you update the same list)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, anyway. Haven't tested this, yet.

#### add_rewrite for to get an extra querystring

Add a rewrite to the specific page (id as `XX`, below).

```
add_rewrite_tag('%chapter%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^story-slug/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=XX&speaker=$matches[1]','top');
```

#### make a template for that specific page.

And create a `page-xx.php` where `xx` is the page ID (or slug) that will make use of an extra piece on the end of the url: `/story-slug/1/` the `1` in this case. Don't forget to include the comments in this template!

In the post editor, write the whole thing as one entry, wrapping the chapters in `[chapter id="X"]`

Then, hide chapters that don't correspond to the url's `chapter` query, via shortcode.

```
add_shortcode('chapter', 'chapter_display')
function chapter_display($atts, $content) {
    $current_chpater = $wp_query->query_vars['chapter'];
    $chapter = $atts['id'];
    if ($chapter == $current_chapter)
        return $content;
}
```

Only thing missing from this solution is pagination across the top / bottom.

By continually referencing the same post, but showing different parts,

PS - don't forget to hit up `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` to flush the rewrite rules after you add the the `add_rewrite_xxx` functions to make sure that they take.

Comment: Cameron, thanks! I think this is too much "advanced" for me... you rock.

Comment: Thanks for saying that! Too bad there's not a plugin for your particular scenario.